# ImportError: cannot import name '_check_weights' from 'sklearn.neighbors._base'

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, missing-data

I am trying to do Missforest as a method for handling missing values in table data.

```
import sklearn
print(sklearn.__version__)
->1.2.1

import sklearn.neighbors._base
import sys
sys.modules['sklearn.neighbors.base'] = sklearn.neighbors._base

!pip install missingpy
from missingpy import MissForest
```

It was working fine until now, but since yesterday, the following error message has appeared.

```
ImportError: cannot import name '_check_weights' from 'sklearn.neighbors._base'
```

I would like to know how to deal with this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the same thing happened to me, I changed the versions of the packages. I have the following setting and it works for me: scikit-learn = 1.1.2, scipy = 1.9.1, missingpy = 0.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `pipwin` to install the appropriate build for your operating system and specific Python version:

Steps:

1. Uninstall current version of sklearn:

   `pip uninstall scikit-learn -y`
2. Install pipwin:

   `pip install pipwin`
3. Install sklearn using pipwin:

   `pipwin install scikit-learn`